# Transparent Status Bar without coordinatorlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, statusbar, android-coordinatorlayout, navigation-drawer

I tried using coordinatorlayout and navigation drawer and making both of them visible under status bar. But when i try to achieve the same thing without coordinator layout it seems impossible to me.

This is what i want

[Coordinatorlayout with transparent status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Je9K.png)

[NavigationView with transparent status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi7fX.png)

xml for the First Example:

activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/background_light"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="8dp"
            android:text="@string/lorem"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            />

        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>



<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_black_24dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is what i am getting without coordinatorlayout

[Layout without coordinatorlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp0uk.png)

As navigation view works correctly in second example

Xml for second example:

activity_no_coordinatorlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<include
    android:id="@+id/child_layout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_below="@id/parent"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

parent_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:src="@drawable/material_flat"
    />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_ content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_comment_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="182dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="31dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post: https://proandroiddev.com/draw-under-status-bar-like-a-pro-db38cfff2870